# Python - Automatically print a value from json file if the updated value is bigger than its previous value

Tags: python, json

Greeting, I'm trying to create a simple continuous function where I get a value from a json file and if that value is updated and bigger than before the update, it will print the new value, I'm not doing it quite right, can anyone help me with this? any help is much appreaciated thanks.

```
import urllib.request, json

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=MYR_INR&compact=y") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    myr_ind = data['MYR_INR']
    val = myr_ind['val']
    previous_value= [0]
while True:
    if val > previous_value[0]:
        previous_value.pop(0)
        previous_value.append(val)
        print(val)
```

Comment: why are you running the while loop? and how the loop is going to be terminated?

Comment: Is the indentation of your `while` statement correct? Shouldn't it be inside the `with`?

Comment: I'm not going to terminate it, I want it to continuously update me with the lastest increasing value, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant to use your `with` block inside your `while` block so that `val` gets updated. Something like this:

```
import urllib.request, json

previous_value = 0

while True:
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=MYR_INR&compact=y") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    myr_ind = data['MYR_INR']
    val = myr_ind['val']

    if val > previous_value:
        previous_value = val
        print(val)
```